Issue that Excel is not displaying enough decimal values for number with repeated decimals
I have an odd issue that I've never come across, and it seems to be specifically to one sheet of an excel file I compiled.
The sheet includes some very precise astronomical formulae, and sometimes the calculated numbers need to he accurate to 12 decimal places.
The issue is that when the calculated value has a repeating decimal, Excel is giving an inappropriately short rounding with a host of trailing zeros. E.g the number that is supposed to be output as 7.760416666667 comes out as 7.760416670000.
I don't know why it is this sheet specifically that is giving this issue. I've looked around online for people having similar issues, but I can't find any. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Does the same number appear in the formula bar? (i.e. the displayed number is not necessarily the number in the cell. Note that 12 decimal positions is close to Excel's limit. This may be informative

If you put the same data in a new worksheet in a new file, does it have the same result?

What is the cell format? If General Number doesn't work, how about using Text?

Thank you for the link cybernetic.nomad. Even if I put the number in the formula barnO get the same issue. The link really explained it well...it's an issue with Excel's accuracy. The real number that it's supposed to display is actually    2445397,760416666667, but since the amount of significant numbers are more than 15 it is displaying it as 2445397.760416670000. Do you have any suggestions for a spreadsheet-like program with greater accuracy than Excel?

@CoenraadvanSchoor - Questions seek software recommendations are out of scope. Why can’t you format the number using an exponent?

Have you tried asking on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ ? The folks there are probably more knowledgeable that us about this kind of software and tool recommendations may be in scope for that forum (check their rules)

Usually, you can improve accuracy by carefully analyzing the order of calculations and avoiding operations that reduce accuracy, such as subtracting numbers that are close to each other.
Increased calculation accuracy is theoretically possible even in Excel using VBA and the Decimal data subtype. However, such calculations are inconvenient, because numbers with increased precision must have a text representation. The matter also becomes more complicated when, in addition to the usual arithmetic operations, functions come into play.
Code of a function that performs basic arithmetic operations with increased accuracy:
Function OpDec(x, y, op)
    Select Case op
       Case "+": OpDec = CStr(CDec(x) + CDec(y))
       Case "-": OpDec = CStr(CDec(x) - CDec(y))
       Case "*": OpDec = CStr(CDec(x) * CDec(y))
       Case "/": OpDec = CStr(CDec(x) / CDec(y))
       Case Else: OpDec = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End Select
End Function

Below is an illustration of the impact of the order in which operations are performed on the accuracy of calculations.
Of course, there are specialized programs like Mathematica that provide virtually any accuracy you need.


In the latest Excel you can use Python. An example of high precision in pure python: from decimal import *;getcontext().prec =64; print(Decimal('1.0')/Decimal('137')) => yields
0.007299270072992700729927007299270072992700729927007299270072992701
